# Kubernetes GCE Internal Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, internal-load-balancer

I'm looking for a way to to create an internal HTTPs L7 ingress controller in GCE, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation in regards to how this can be done. I see that there is a way to create an internal a L4 LoadBalancer, but not an L7 ingress. Why is this the case and what are possible solutions or workarounds?

Comment: I believe there’s no internal L7 load balancer / Ingress yet on GKE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an "internal" ingress-controller setup you simply do not need to expose your `Service` as type `LoadBalancer. Your ingress-controller will be accessible via the node port.'

If you're wanting an actual load balancer in front of your ingress you'll have to roll your own such as HAproxy.